# Files not showing up when I open it through text editor in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, file, window

I'm doing a Udemy course and I downloaded the files from github. The files show what's inside when I open them from the desktop. But when I try to open the files through the editor nothing is showing up inside the files. Anyone know how to fix this? I can't find anything on Google about the issue. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Can you share a link or example of one of these files?

Comment: https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/complete-javascript-course

Comment: This seems like a well-used repository with standard file formats that should work in most code editors. What editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Brackets

Comment: I found these issues that might be applicable to you (https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10718, https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12617). The editor you use is up to you, but I'd consider installing another free editor such as VSCode and trying it there.

Comment: Will do. Thank you!